# How to properly code an array to mysql db with a select multiple

Tags: php, html, mysql

As a new programmer I'm having trouble figuring out how to exactly code this situation. I've taken some of the solutions via stackoverflow but this one doesn't seem to work as I thought it would. I have a  tag that correctly puts in one selected item but if I put in two or three it gives me the numbers. I.e. if I selected 3 options with id's 3, 5 and 8 it turns into 358 instead of creating a many-to-many catalog relationship of 3-3, 3-5, 3-8.

The purpose is that the form is creating a new character that can gain several disadvantages. These disadvantages are then linked to the new characters unique id.

```
$query2 = implode ( "",$_POST['did']);
                $sql="INSERT INTO player_disadvantage
                (disadvantageid,characterid)
                VALUES ('".$query2."',LAST_INSERT_ID())"
                ;

  <tr>
<td>Disadvantages</td>
<td>
  <?php

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM disadvantages");
echo '<SELECT multiple="multiple" id="did" name="did[]">';
  while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $disadvantages = $row1['name'];
  $disadvantagesid = $row1['did'];
  $disadvantagescost = $row1['cost'];
echo "<option value='".$disadvantagesid."'>". '+' . ' ' . $disadvantagescost . ' ' . $disadvantages .  "</option>";   
  }
       echo '</select>';
?>
    </td>
```

My only guess is to find a way to move the code so that it puts the LAST_INSERT_ID() with every disadvantage id. I'm not sure how to code it.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure how to roll out the last_insert_id that can match up with the disadvantage many-to-many option

Comment: so what `last_insert_id` would the first row have?

Comment: There are 5 different tables I have to access-- and so the last_insert_id will be the same charid for all of them. So for disadvantages it would be the same for all the rows. If that makes sense and I understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$values = implode(',', array_map(function($x) {
    return "('" . mysql_real_escape_string($x) . "', LAST_INSERT_ID())"; },
  $_POST['did']));
$sql = "INSERT INTO player_disadvantage (disadvantageid, characterid) VALUES $values";
```

This creates a query that looks like:

```
INSERT INTO player_disadvantage (disadvantageid, characterid)
VALUES ('3', LAST_INSERT_ID()),
       ('5', LAST_INSERT_ID()),
       ('8', LAST_INSERT_ID())
```

to add multiple rows.

Comment: This inserts an ID of 0 several of my other attempts have done the same. LAST_INSERT_ID is working though as I have another insert (no array) that inserts the auto incremented id successfully. So I'm guessing then that this isn't grabbing the last id properly??

Comment: Did you add the row to your player table immediately before this, and with the same SQL connection? `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is specific to an SQL session.

Comment: That was poor communication on my part- the disadvantage id is 0. I'll copy the echo. "INSERT INTO playerskill (skillid, charid) VALUES ('2',LAST_INSERT_ID())Character was approved.INSERT INTO player_disadvantage (disadvantageid, characterid) VALUES ('',LAST_INSERT_ID())Character was approved.did".

Comment: If you're getting `VALUES ('', LAST_INSERT_ID())`, it means that there was an empty value in `$_POST['did']`. You need to do input validation before performing the insert.

Comment: Thank you I was able to get it to work after re validating it.